# What is the password to the chest?

Tags: the-gold-factory

I buried myself in the sand and beat the guy in a battle down the bottom. I put the key in the chest he gave me and now it needs a password. What is it? I have been told it was fox related and that it was 
*Ring-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding!* but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that Ring-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding! is the correct password. We just figured it out ourselves before we came here.

Comment: The OP has stated `Ring-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding` (your answer) does not work.

Comment: It worked for us - perhaps he didn't have the exclamation point on the end